# CSS is not recognised by browser in localhost

Tags: html, css, localserver

I am creating a login/registration system and I have created a folder structure within xampp as below: htdocs > login_and_registration > css > includes > and then a number of files which are not within a folder. I managed to access the files by changing the permissions for them, however, the browser is not recognising the css and returns a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). The reference to the css in my file is /css/boostrap.css and css/style.css and this was referenced via the "stylesheet' and link href. I am not sure what needs to be done to resolve this, however. Can anyone advise, please? Thanks.

Comment: 404 error usually comes when the path your provided is wrong, permission here nothing matters, check once again the source path you given to css file

Comment: I figured it out thank you. It was the file path, but I had to check the properties to make sure. Thank you

Comment: happy to help. enjoy coding;-)